# Translucent leaves in my echeveria

Tags: diagnosis, diseases

I have a problem with my echeveria, when I received it all its leaves where pointing up but then started to decay as if they where plastic in a hot place but I see new leaves so I think it was the normal cycle. However now the leaves are getting translucent like if they are converting into water.

I have water only 2 times in 5 months, because friends also got another and water them every month and got dead by the same symptoms of mine and I though the problem was too much water.

About the light and environment, it doesn't receive direct sun light and is in a interior not near windows. Maybe is because it needs more light?

Here are some photographs of the plant:

[image: Close up image of the leaves]
[image: With flash]
[image: Translucent leaves details]
[image: General view of the plant]

Answer (score 4):

This translucence, coupled with reddening of the lower leaves, is not part of this plant's 'normal cycle', but more a cry for help. It definitely needs more light and likely more water than you've allowed it so far, given it's summer.

Echeveria needs bright daylight with some sun, although protection from very hot sun through a window in high summer is advisable,especially in the middle of the day. If you can find a well lit spot on a windowsill with, say, some morning or evening sun, that should improve the situation, if its not already too late. Full sun in winter is not a problem and may be beneficial. They also demand fresh air flow, so an open window nearby will provide that. This plant does better with a marked difference between day and night temperatures - keep cool in winter, 50 to 55 degF is ideal, particularly overnight.

Despite its requirement to be kept relatively dry, during the summer months, this plant should be watered well once the top of the compost is dry to the touch, allowing the pot to drain down freely and never leaving water in the bottom of a tray or outer pot - that should be emptied away after 30 minutes, or until no more water has collected. Reduce watering as winter approaches and water sparingly during winter, maybe every 1-2 months, depending on the temperatures its exposed to in your home (it may dry out more quickly in a very warm room) to prevent shrivelling.

Do not fertilize the plant while its in such a bad condition, it won't help at all and may make things worse. If you can find somewhere sunny for it, you will need to acclimatize it gradually to direct sun, given it's currently so light deprived - strong sunlight all day at the moment is likely to kill it, so introduce sunlight gradually, starting maybe with an hour or so in the morning or late afternoon.

Comment: I think I have a good spot for it that I think it has your requirements. I will see if it get better.

Comment: Fingers crossed!

Comment: Make sure you get rid of the outer pot...Bamboo your answers are so dependable!!  I learn so very much from you...

Answer (score 1):

It could be a nitrogen deficiency.

As you can see, the apex (top part of the plant) is still growing new "leaves". It requires a lot of energy from the plant. Usually, the growing phase is associated to a large consumption of nitrogen; nutrient used for leave and stem development.

Nitrogen deficiency can be diagnostic by a purple-red color on stem and, for some species, on the leaves. The noticable light green (near transparency) of the newer leaves can be an hint too.

To balance deficiency you could use grow fertilizer (with a high ratio of N) or simply use one of this natural source of nitrogen :

- ashes,
- nettles (manure),
- green waste compost.